# What does the consistency condition mean in IPTW?

Tags: econometrics, causality, endogeneity

From the paper **On the Consistency Rule in Causal Inference: Axiom, Definition, Assumption, or Theorem?**  Pearl (2010):

> Informally, the consistency rule states that a person’s potential outcome under a
>   hypothetical condition that happened to materialize is precisely the outcome experienced
>   by that person.

I have a hard time understanding this sentence. What does this mean? Is this related to endogeneity in standard econometrics?

Could someone help met out? Kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine there is a link between a treatment level, $a$, and a potential outcome, $Y(a)$. For example, say the following links exist:

$$0 \rightarrow Y(0) \\1 \rightarrow Y(1) $$

Consistency says that when an individual receives a value of treatment, their observed outcome $Y$ *is* the potential outcome linked to that treatment. It's not some other value.

We can think of each individual having many potential outcomes inside them. The goal of causal inference is to estimate the difference between these potential outcomes; each difference corresponds to the causal contrast between the different treatments. When we assign an individual to a treatment value, we reveal one of their potential outcomes. Consistency says that the potential outcome that we reveal is the potential outcome that corresponds to the treatment actually received.

For some nice introductions from perspectives other than Pearl's, I recommend [Cole & Frangakis (2009)](https://doi.org/10.1097/EDE.0b013e31818ef366) and [Hernán & Taubman (2008)](https://doi.org/10.1038/ijo.2008.82).